# Script binding does not work before calling Script.run()

Tags: variables, groovy, binding, integration

I've the following test code to figure out how variable binding works. So this is what I want to import/include;

```
# importee.groovy
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field top = 60
number = 44 // binding variable
int ratio = 4.5

return this
```

which I call it from;

```
# importer.groovy (version1)
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader

def gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()                                           
def clazz = gcl.parseClass(new File("importee.groovy"))    )
assert clazz.name == 'importee' 
def script = clazz.newInstance()   
//script.run()
println("binding variable: 
${script.getBinding().getVariable("number")}")
```

So, if I don't run the script, my test code throws "MissingPropertyException" on the last print statement. This is not happenning if I call `def script = evaluate(new File("importee.groovy"))` instead of using `GroovyClassLoader` like this;

```
# importer.groovy (version2)
def script = evaluate(new File("importee.groovy"))
println("binding/global variable: ${script.number}")
```

Since both methods return a `Script` instance, I got a little bit confused on why I have to call the `run()` method in the first case. Can someone explain where I fail to understand please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `groovyconsole` (distributed with groovy)

type a simple script:

```
number=44
return this
```

select menu `Script -> Inspect Ast`

and in the new window `Groovy AST Browser` select `phase = Conversion`

you will see your groovy script but converted to a Script class like this:

```
public class script1548245785832 extends groovy.lang.Script { 
    public script1548245785832() {
    }

    public java.lang.Object run() {
        number = 44
        return this 
    }
}
```

this is the actual code generated for your script.

as you can see the constructor is empty, so no information about `number` property after you call `newInstance()`

but after you call `run()` you actually run your script.

---

your script could be a class like this:

```
class Importee {
    int number=44
    public Object run(){
        println number
    }
}
```

in this case it will be enough to create instance of class without calling `run()` method and get the value of number variable...

```
def clazz = gcl.parseClass( new File("Importee.groovy")) )
def script = clazz.newInstance()   

println("the variable: ${script.number}")
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice tool :). Thanks. And this is a subtle difference IMO. So, the point is the code inside the run() method needs to be executed to evaluate that variable, right? In case of calling the evalute(new File(...)), the run method is executed already so that's why I see the variable "number".